# Video extension "After the monitor" solution?

Tags: monitors, video, kvm

I have a customer who is looking to extend the output of a weather station into a second aircraft hangar at an airport.  The vendor has approved doing this, but says that any solution we implement must be done "after the monitor." The output is a single VGA port.

They have explained that this means the signal must go from the station to the primary display without any interruption in signal.  I am looking for a way to use an ethernet based or even IP based extender in this configuration.

Does a monitor with a video-out passthrough exist? The requirement for uninterrupted signal to the main display leaves out the use of a splitter device, but I am wondering if they will allow a passive Y-Cable.  We are checking on that, but I am looking for alternatives if that falls through.

EDIT: The vendor confirmed that a splitter cable is NOT acceptable, so a pass-through monitor would be the only option.

Comment: Some Monitors have displayPort in and out, not sure about VGA, which appears to be your only option

Comment: Can you recommend or direct to me to such a monitor?  I was unable to find such a beast.

Comment: off the top of my head, the p2715q does displayport passthrough, though you trade off half your refresh rate for that. Its 4K tho, and pretty high end.

Comment: @LarryM, - several of Dell's Ultrasharps can, such as the U2715H

Comment: What if you point a camera at the primary display?

Comment: @Random832 We considered this option, but it seemed like too much of a workaround hack than a true and professional solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the solution is one of two possible options.  There is a DisplayPort standard called Multi-Stream Transport (MST) that was introduced with DisplayPort 1.2 (Wikipedia, n.d.).  The other option is a display with a VGA in/out configuration.  LG makes a series of monitors that provides this function, the N225WU-BN Cloud monitor, which is designed for use with Microsoft Multipoint Server 2011, but serves the purpose for this application (N225WU-BN, n.d.).

I wanted to thank SSumner for the DisplayPort research direction.

References

*DisplayPort*. (n.d.). Retrieved November 6, 2015, from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Multiple_displays_on_single_DisplayPort_connector

*N225WU-BN*. (n.d.). Retrieved November 6, 2015, from http://www.lg.com/us/commercial/desktop-virtualization/lg-N225WU-BN